# Vegetable Soup Missing Something Fundamental?

Tags: substitutions, vegetables, soup, salt

In response to the "on hold", I'll attempt to make the question more clear and specific. Is there an ingredient or ingredients (or technique) that is missing from the below recipe that all or nearly all vegetable soup recipes use and might be considered fundamental? Salt was mentioned. Although it is present, it has been minimized. If that's the only real "fundamental" ingredient, then that's just the price I am paying. Another suggestion was browning the onions, which I will try. Another was adding a spice or spices that are a matter of personal taste. I'm sure I'll try that too, but more to the spirit of the question would be whether there is a spice or spices that is nearly always used in this type of tomato-y vegetable soup.

---

I've put together a loose vegetable soup recipe that works passably for me and is not *too* time-consuming every couple of weeks, but it's clearly missing something to "bring it together". Hopefully that something is not the salt that I am intentionally minimizing (for health reasons -- see end of question). I don't add any spices (unless you count the garlic) because I don't know what I'm doing and it seems they can change the soup drastically -- for example too much oregano. I'm hoping that I'm missing something fundamental and that there are some relatively objective fixes. Currently, it's basically "throw in a lot of vegetables that I like and that are convenient, and add some broth", but *slightly* more refined. It varies frequently, but remains close to what's below.

I hope that my request is specific enough to be appropriate.

> Olive Oil, about 2 tablespoons
> Onions*, Diced, about 2 Medium
> Carrots*, Diced, volume about equal to onions
> Celery*, Diced, volume about equal to onions
> * *supermarket sometimes has fresh diced mirepoix which I use for convenience*
> Mushrooms, Diced/Minced, 1 Box
> Mushrooms, Sliced, 1 Box
> Garlic*, Minced, 1 Heaping Tablespoon
> * *I use a store bought jar made by "Bellino" -- don't hate me*
> Tomatoes, Petit Cut No Salt Added, 1 Can
> Tomato Salsa (mild), Fresh, 1 Box
> Wine, Red, 1 "Justin Wilson" Ounce
> Corn, 1 Frozen Bag
> Beans (Red Kidney, Cannellini, or Soy/Edamame), Low Sodium, 1-2 Cans/Frozen Bags
> Chicken Broth, Low Sodium, "enough"
> Baby Spinach, Chiffonade, Half Bag to 1 Bag
>
> In a large pot (I use a clad pot that I *think* is 7 quarts but is not labelled), heat a couple of tablespoons of olive oil. Add either the mushrooms first or the mirepoix (onions, carrots, celery) first -- I've tried both variations. Try to get a little color on the mushrooms and sweat the onions. Note I do NOT add salt to help sweat the onions. Turn down the burner and avoid browning the onions.
>
> Once the mix looks subjectively good, add the garlic and stir it in. Let it heat up, again without browning. Then add the tomatoes and tomato salsa. If there appears to be "enough" liquid, add the wine now. If not, add some broth and then the wine. Cover and simmer/low-boil for "a while" (10 minutes?). My idea here is to extract alcohol soluble flavors from the tomatoes.
>
> Add corn and beans and enough broth to cover everything well. This usually nearly fills the pot. Cover and simmer/low-boil for another "while" (30 minutes?). Now mix in spinach, cover, and simmer/low-boil for another "while" (15 minutes?).

That's it. It's passable and holds me over for maybe a week, but the taste is clearly missing something. Is there a standard step/ingredient in soup-making that I am completely missing? I was planning on experimenting with adding some tomato paste with the garlic. Maybe I need some spices? I would like to keep salt to a minimum. Thanks.

Background: I'm overweight with high cholesterol and moderately high blood pressure. I'm trying to loose weight an be more healthy. Vegetable soup is a perfect fit for me. I enjoy it and don't mind eating it on a (very) regular basis, plus it's a pretty healthy and low-calorie (per unit volume) choice. Unfortunately, I'm not a natural cook and don't have lots of time to cook, and canned choices are generally sub-optimal (particularly the sodium).

Comment: This boils down to "use salt" (really), or what goes with this recipe, which is off topic.   You have enough rep to join us in [chat]; I suggest coming over and asking there.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll give it a little time to see if there are any other opinions. If not, should I delete?

Comment: That is up to you; it might get closed anyway.

Comment: Why are you avoiding browning? Browning is free flavor.

Comment: @KateGregory I used an old vegetable soup recipe as a basis many years ago -- I think it was the weight watchers vegetable/cabbage soup that was 0 points. As I recall it said to sweat the onions but not to brown them and I took it on faith as I know nothing about making soup. In fact, I recall I had to look up what it meant to "sweat onions". If browning the onions is a good idea in vegetable soup I'll gladly give it a try.

Comment: I agree with Kate, the browning will really help. Also, if you make your own stock you can get even more flavor out of it (brown the bones and veggies for the stock, add things like mushrooms and kombu to maximize umami, etc).

Comment: Personal "choice", but try making it without oil - since you are using chicken broth anyway....

Comment: I saw your edit. Maybe I shouldn't have gone with the closing reasons the other ones suggested, because the canned text going with it is somewhat misleading. It is clear what you are asking, the problem is more that it is not clear how we can answer. "Taste missing" is a matter of familiarity and perception, there is nothing without a soup is not "whole" but if you are accustomed to always eating soup with, say, nutmeg, you will miss it if it is not there, while others won't even like soup with nutmeg. You already acknowledged that the salt is missing; we can't know what else you are (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) personally accustomed to, or even if there is something beyond the salt. Starting to suggest ingredients at random won't help - it is like saying "I lost something from my bag but don't know what" and people at the "lost and found" starting to show you pens, wallets, umbrellas and whatever else they have - the chance that you can get whatever you are missing are very low. We can't reopen the question, because we don't have a chance of giving you a good answer. On the bright side, if it *is* the salt you are missing, your taste will transition to accept lowered salt with time.

Comment: @rumtscho Thanks for your feedback. I'll take the advice I've gotten so far and try to experiment. When I have some time I may also take the advice of SAJ14SAJ and bounce a few ideas around in chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do some kind of spice to help your soup. What kind should be up to you, basics like bay leaf or parsley are always a good start. You could go with a grouping like basil and oregano or dill might work with the spinach in the soup. That is all up to you, also you might try a couple of drops of low sodium soy sauce to give you some of that salty tang.